# Remove Vertical Space

Tags: html, css

How could I remove the vertical space between the objects while using `inline-book` ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/35/)

I want keep different height for the cards, and make a fixed vertical space between them :

Update :
I want make the space of blue's circles exactly same gold's circles without change any thing else: 
 [image]

Comment: Are you sure you mean *vertical* (between lines) and not *horizontal* - between each box - which is more typical for `inline-block` elements?

Comment: Remove the class font-size-0

Comment: @KobiI I attached image

Comment: In the jsfiddle class inline-block is missing in the CSS. Does it exist?

Comment: You want cards have same height. Or you want cards clear the vertical spaces but still have different height ?

Comment: cards clear the vertical spaces but still have different height  - yes this one @thanhnha1103

Comment: You cannot have the same vertical space between these two 'boxes' because the boxes themselves have different heights. You have multiple rows of these boxes that sit on top of each other. The only way to have the same vertical space between is if the boxes were of same height.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

New line is treated as one space when `display:inline-block` is used. You can either

1. Put everything in a single line without any spacing in between

```css
.btn {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.txt {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #77FF77;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div>
```

2. Add comments in between `<div>` and `</div>` (again without any spacing in between)

```css
.btn {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.txt {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #77FF77;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div><!--
--><div class="btn"><div class="txt inline-block"></div></div>
```

For the vertical space, you can add `margin-bottom: 5px;` to `.btn`

Comment: Didn't work, because of I have t classes btn, txt. I want remove the space vertically between them

Comment: This is a good answer for horizontal spaces, but looks like the OP is concerned about the vertical space. I'm not sure what the expected result is though.

Comment: @sam updated the answer as well. And what do you mean by *without changing anything else*?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXpxbo

I was unable to use the built in code snippet as your html is too long so instead I used codepen.  Hopefully this helps.

```
.btn {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.font-size-0 {
    font-size: 0;
}
.txt {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #77FF77;
}

:matches( .btn, .font-size-0, .txt){
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don not use `display:inline-block;` try to use `float:left;` and see if it works. I hope it will.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/50/ have a look now. is this something you are looking for?

Comment: close but no, you change the height of objects, I want keep height same , but the space between the (object1) and the (object2) bellow (object1) make it dynamic

Comment: I want keep different height for the cards, and make a fixed vertical space between them

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-bottom` property to `btn` class

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these 3 lines to .txt class.

```
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/67/

Comment: Not this what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS columns: http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/112/

In this case I wrapped all boxes in another `div`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

And set it to columns:

```
.wrapper {
  column-width:14px; /* 12px width + 2px border */
  column-gap: 0; /* you can use 4px for some space between columns */
}
```

Another option is to use flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/79/ - but I think it is less robust: you have to set the height of the wrapper element, and the width of the boxes may vary.

Either way, this changes the order in which your elements are displayed - instead of line by line, the second box will be *under* the first box.

Comment: @sam - maybe this: http://jsfiddle.net/e6raLLc5/90/ Honestly, you should include an example of what it should look like - most people here are guessing wrong (including me). I'm guessing Pinterest style columns.